# getting the base sku (Without a suffix) of a product with custom options

Tags: magento-1.9

I am facing a problem in which i need to retrieve the base sku of a product on the modified sku of that product which has the custom option sku suffixed.

for example> base product "shirt", sku = 1234,
                             "red shirt"= 1234-12
how can i get the sku of the base "shirt" (1234) from the "red shirt"(1234-12)
please take note that this isnt a case of "configurable products". and there doesnt exist in parent child relationship between the original and sub products(and parents are returned as "null"

Answer (score 0):

Am I right in assuming that you're trying to get the SKU from a quote, cart or order item and it's returning the SKU in the extended format you mention? That's normal if you're just using `$cartItem->getSku()`, you need to get the *product* from the cart item and then get the SKU from that e.g.

`$cartItem->getProduct()->getSku()`